# DECLARATION error in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a trigger in **MySQL** with the following code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_b_l_tuteur
BEFORE INSERT ON tuteur FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE code_err_tut integer;
   DECLARE nb integer :=0;
   DECLARE vliberlleErr MSG_ERREUR.libelleErr%TYPE;

   SELECT libelleErr INTO vlibellErr FROM MSG_ERREUR WHERE   codeErr=code_err_tut; 
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nb FROM ETUDIANT e WHERE :NEW.idUser = e.idUser;

   if(nb<>0) then
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(CODE_ERR_TUTEUR, vlibelleErr);
   end if;

END
```

And I get an SQL error saying:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4 "
>
> The line 4 is : " DECLARE code_err_tut integer;

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please post the code and not screenshot of it.

Comment: thanks to @infaustus for the edit proposition

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to change your delimiter, so the first `;` in your query (line 4) 
terminates the entire trigger definition, making "declare" invalid.

Try

```
DELIMITER $$   // note this line
CREATE yada yada yada
end if;
END
DELIMITER ;  // note this line
```